# Why does printfn print immediately in f#?

Tags: f#

When I run the following bit of code, I get 5050 printed out from mySum. I've defined mySum, but never invoked it. How can it print at all? Maybe this is weird because my background is Haskell and I'm used to passing the IO monad around to get things to do stuff - how/when are things evaluated in F#?

```
type main = obj [] -> int

let mySum =  [1..100] |> List.sum |> printfn "%i"


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I've defined mySum, but never invoked it.

`mySum` is not a function, as it takes no parameters. A function has to have at least one argument; if nothing "useful" can be passed, that will usually be the `unit` value `()`.

`mySum` is a value; more specifically, you are binding the value of the expression `[1..100] |> List.sum |> printfn "%i"` to the name `mySum`. That value in turn is `()`, as `printfn` only causes a side effect and returns `unit`. The expression is evaluated immediately when the value is bound, and all that remains are the side effect and the actual value.

As a function, `mySum` would look like this:

```
let mySum () =  [1..100] |> List.sum |> printfn "%i"
```

And calling it would simply be

```
mySum ()
```

That would cause the value `5050` to be printed out, and the return value of `()` would be automatically ignored.

Comment: This is so weird. What's a value? Isn't 5 a function that gives back a 5? Very different paradigm.

Comment: If `5` was a function that gives back a `5`, then wouldn't that second `5` also be a function that gives back a `5`, and so on? At some point you have to have values. Are you coming from Haskell by any chance?

Comment: My personal opinion from my very limited (and not very positive) experience with Haskell is that for first getting into F#, a Haskell mindset isn't very helpful, because the languages indeed have somewhat different approaches. The most important thing to be aware of here is that unlike Haskell, F# is not a pure(ly) functional language. Once F# and its specific "quirks" become more natural, Haskell thinking probably gets more valuable again.

Comment: Yeah, coming from Haskell. There are no values, only realizations of the IO monad.